# How do i get the id of the channel the channel my discord bot is in and the channel id of the message author

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a discord bot leave command but i cant find what i have to put to get the channel id of the bot and the user sending the message to compare and make sure they are the same

```
Crashbot.on('message', async message =>{

    //creates an array called args and removes the first amount of charactors equal to the length of the prefix variable
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    //the switch equals true if the first word after the prefix is "leave"
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'leave':
    
        //if the message author is not in the same voice channel as the bot the bot replies and tells them that that have to be in the same channel to use that command
        if (message.member.voice.channel.id != Crashbot.voice.channel.id) {
            message.reply("You must be in the same channel as me to use this command");
        return;
        }

    //if the message author is in the same voice channel as the bot it leaves the channel it is in
    if (message.member.voice.channel.id === Crashbot.voice.channel.id) {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.leave()
            message.channel.send("Successfully left the voice channel");
    }
    break;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Discord.js Docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientVoiceManager).

You can use `client.voice.connections` to get a collection of voice connections. You can use this to check if the channel id the user is in matches any in the connections.

Comment: So how would i use that to get the actual user and bot voice channel ids and then compare them to make sure they match?